# Understanding how something can be AND-ed with just a negation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

pretty simple really, what is the below expresion saying?

$\psi$ is a set, and $\alpha \vdash \neg \land \psi$

This is the first time I've seen a negation negating an AND. Isn't the negation of an expression, not a logical connective?

Comment: It looks like a typo. More context would help figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

It could be $\neg \bigwedge \psi$, where $\bigwedge \psi$ is the conjunction of all elements of $\psi$ (so this is asuming that$\psi$ is a set of statements).

Example:

$\psi = \{ P, Q, R \lor S\}$

Then $\bigwedge \psi = P \land Q \land (R \lor S)$

And so $\neg \bigwedge \psi = \neg (P \land Q \land (R \lor S))$

In other words, the $\bigwedge$ is for conjunction as what $\Sigma$ is for addition

... see if that makes sense in the context where you found this expression ...